# Manage Undo across multiple NSTextFields in the same window

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsundomanager

While Undo for multiple `NSTextView`s in a window work persistently, the same is not the case for `NSTextField` controls by default.

I like to make Undo behave the same for `NSTextField` as it works with `NSTextView`.

I have so far found out that `NSTextField` uses its own private `NSUndoManager`, which does enable and handle the Undo/Redo menus autmatically, but without using the window's shared `undoManager`, and without marking the connected document dirty ("edited"): If I provide a private `NSUndoManager` instance to an `NSTextField`, it'll behave the same.

So I've tried, by overwriting `undoManagerForTextView:`, to have the `NSTextField`s in the window use the window's shared `undoManager`. That will indeed lead to the effect that the text fields share the same undo stack, and I can still issue an Undo after editing and then leaving a specific text field.

However, the problem is that it'll then crash, because it appears that the Undo gets applied to the wrong (i.e. the currently active) text field and not to the one the undo action was created from.

I've provided a simple example here: https://github.com/tempelmann/Undo_shared_NSTextFields

It's a freshly created document based app, with two text fields and two text views in the main window. To enable the shared undo manager for the text fields, I've created a subclass ("CustomTextField") of `NSTextField` that overrides the following function to provide the shared undo manager:

```objc
-(NSUndoManager *)undoManagerForTextView:(NSTextView *)view { // NSTextViewDelegate
    return view.window.undoManager;
}
```

And the text fields in the storyboard are set to this subclass instead of `NSTextField`.

When run, it looks like this:

[image: window with 4 edit controls]

Now, if you edit the first and the second **text view**, and then use Undo twice, it'll undo the changes in each text view just fine.

But if you try the same with the two **text fields**, e.g. by replacing the longer preset texts in the fields with something shorter (such as "1" and "2"), you'll find that Undo replaces the text in the same active text field twice:

[image]

How do I make Undo in the text fields behave correctly, i.e. the same as the text views do?

Comment: Did you have a look at how mail.app does it? I’d assume the mail-composition window to have a similar gui/problem.

Comment: Use `NSTextView` instead of `NSTextField`?

Comment: @Karsten In my tests with Mail.app, editing both the subject and the body text, then pressing Undo multiple times, it only undoes edits in the current field, e.g. in the body, but not in the subject. Which means that the undo stacks are private to each field, which is the opposite of what I try to achieve.